# Store accessor issue : Can't read old already stored json object serialized ( hash ) values in mysql database in Rails 4

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I am upgrading my application to Rails 4.2.4 from Rails 3.2.8 . I have a 'extras' attribute for a table 'editorials' which is serialized

```
    store :extras, accessors: [:attr1, :attr2, :attr3], coder: JSON

    #The way it is stored in **Rails 3** is 

    ---
    :attr1: value
    :attr2: value
    :attr3: value

   #The way it is stored in **Rails 4** is
   {"attr1":"value", "attr2":"value", "attr3":"value"}
```

The problem when i fetch old records created when my app is in rails 3, it is throwing me error

```
JSON::ParserError: 795: unexpected token at '---
```

But when i create new records, it is working normally. Have not got any clue yet, how it get it working in Rails 4

Comment: About strore accessor http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Store.html

Comment: Well, it's stored in yaml, not json. Did you change serializers during the upgrade?

Comment: No i have not changed anything.

Comment: Though activerecord version is changed from 3.2.13 to 4.2.4

Comment: And `coder: JSON` was always there?

Comment: Yes, the coder is JSON

Comment: @Sergio, I am able to solve this, thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution finally. The "store accessor" (mentioned in the question) implementation is changed in activerecord 4.2.4. Earlier(active record 3.2.8 ) the data is stored in database is in YAML format, and it was working with "coder: JSON", which is not case in activerecord 4.2.4

Here is the code link 4.2.4
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/store.rb#L85

Here is the code link 3.2
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/store.rb#L35

Now in 4.2.4, whether the data stored in serialized attribute is in YAML or JSON, the coder that is working for me now is YAML.

Hence my code was starting working after i changed the coder from JSON to YAML.

Any question/doubt about this answer will be appreciated.

Comment: So it was storing YAML even though you specified JSON? How treacherous :)