# Store stops working when upgrading to Rails 4.0 from 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am upgrading my Rails application from **v3.2 to v4.0**. In my `User` model I have a JSON coded Store:

```
store :settings, accessors: [
  :confirmed,
  :receive_marketing_emails,
  :receive_reply_emails
], coder: JSON
```

This works as expected, serializing `User.settings` and providing accessors.

However when I move to Rails 4.0 the Store stops working. I get the following error when I attempt to look up any User:

```
JSON::ParserError: 795: unexpected token at '---
:confirmed,
:receive_marketing_emails,
:receive_reply_emails
'
```

Can anyone provide any insight?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per [this question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33539866/store-accessor-issue-cant-read-old-already-stored-json-object-serialized-ha):

> Earlier (ActiveRecord 3.2.8) the data is stored in database is in YAML format, and it was working with "coder: JSON", which is not case in ActiveRecord 4.2.4.

So even though you would specify `coder: JSON`, the data was being serialized to YAML, and not JSON. Strange.

To answer my own question, in Rails 4.0 I just had to change `coder: JSON` to `coder: YAML`.

Answer (score 0):

There is this statement in the [Rails Upgrade Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#active-model):

> Rails 4.0 has changed ActiveModel::Serializers::JSON.include_root_in_json default value to false. Now, Active Model Serializers and Active Record objects have the same default behavior.

I'd suggest that when you are accessing a `User` instance, the json field cannot be deserialized since it expects no root, while the serialized data has it.

To revert to Rails 3.2 behaviour, put this in your `config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb`:

```
ActiveSupport.on_load(:active_record) do
  self.include_root_in_json = true
end
```

Comment: Hi Nic thanks for the response! We've actually had `include_root_in_json` set to false since 3.2, so the serialized data would've never had a root, right?

Comment: In this case my suggestion is probably not relevant. To make sure whether the root is in place you should check the raw data in the database though.